# How can I sort multiple tables i export from an sql database to excel by date?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have searched for help with this extensively but haven't been able to figure it out. This is my first attempt at asking a question here so please bare with.

I have a project called www.farmathand.com where farmers keep track of their field activities through multiple pre-defined forms and a few dynamic forms. These forms then have an associated date with them to keep a record of when something was done. Here's a screen shot

[image]

Farmers have the ability to export all their entered information into an excel file. The problem I am having is figuring out a solution so sort the activities by date. Currently I have simple export code that looks and print data from each table (i.e. each type of activity) then moves on the to the next able. The fields in each table differ as you can see in the image. 
Here is a screen shot of an excel file for the above example: [image]

What i would like to be able to do is sort the activities by the date. So in the example in the above image. Line 7 would be at the top or like one should be line 6.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggesting or could guide me to the appropriate reference. The data base is a mysql database. I'm running php scripts currently.

Comment: If you can standardize the output you could do a union. The biggest problem I see is it is two (or more) different types of data (harvest vs seeding vs ??) so you aren't returning a consistent dataset (same # of columns all named the same) that you can merge and sort.

Comment: I think it all depends on the format you save the date in.

Comment: To follow on from Omnikrys comment, you could perhaps have a master sheet listing every activity in date order but only showing the fields common to all activities (Category Name, Sub Category, Activity Date, Note) You could then have individual sheets for each category (e.g. Seeding, Harvest) which show the full details for each activity in that category

Comment: Thank you for you response. After some configuring we were able to run a type of a loop to export each different table and then sort by date. 

Thank you again for taking the time to provide your input. It's much appreciated as this was my first time using Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then what you want is to include an `ORDER BY` clause in your select query to sort the data. More information here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Thank you for you response. After some configuring we were able to run a type of a loop to export each different table and then sort by date. 

Thank you again for taking the time to provide your input. It's much appreciated as this was my first time using Stackoverflow.